# Need some guidance understanding what EF Core does with this query internally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am constructing this IQueryable in code:

```
var query = (from t in context.Tasks.AsNoTracking()
         join wt in context.WorkTemplates on t.ID equals wt.TaskID into tmp
         from tt in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty(new WorkTemplate())
         group tt by t into grp
         select new
         {
             grp.Key.ID,
             grp.Key.Name,
             grp.Key.Instructions,
             grp.Key.ManualOnly,
             grp.Key.Timestamp,
             TemplateCount = grp.Where(x => x.ID > 0).Count()
         })
         .Select(x => new Task { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, Instructions = x.Instructions, ManualOnly = x.ManualOnly, Timestamp = x.Timestamp, TemplateCount = x.TemplateCount })
         .AsQueryable();
```

My requirement is that it has to be a single IQueryable statement because it is handed off to a grid control that uses it to fetch data in an on-going fashion.

EF Core 2.2.6 did not complain about this query, but apparently that was because it was doing what it had to in order to execute at least part of it locally.  Now that I have moved to EF Core 5+, it throws this exception:

[image]

I think the problem is the `group` part of the query.  It is there because it derives the `TemplateCount`, but I can't find a way to rewrite this that works.

Since this query is never going to pull enough data to cause a performance problem, local execution is fine.  It is more important that it works as a single IQueryable.

Comment: It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between *entities*. If you have to write explicit joins, something's wrong with the model

Comment: Please read the exception message.

Comment: `EF Core 2.2.6 did not complain ` on the contrary, it generated a warning that the query couldn't be translated. The query already had a bug (on top of the problematic model), but EF Core only issued a warning. It's EF Core 3 that explicitly disabled client-side evaluation.

Comment: If the entities had proper relations and you wanted to find the number of templates per task, you could select all Tasks and for each task select `Templates.Count()`, eg `context.Tasks.Select(task=>new {Task=task,Count=t.Templates.Count()})`

Comment: @IanKemp Profound advice, right there.  I'll be sure to get right on that...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, and true.  But right now that is not an option, I just have to fix this as it is.

Comment: Why isn't that option? You clearly have access to the code, otherwise you couldn't fix it. So you should be able to create a navigation property as suggested (`t.Templates`), which is really not hard at all and with EF 5 core the only way to get this done.

Comment: The problem that needs fixing first is the model. After that, the error is clear - the query is trying something that simply can't be translated into SQL. Grouping by an entire object is certainly weird, especially when you *don't* want to group by that object at all.

Comment: What does "constructing this query in code" mean exactly? EF Core's handling of group by is very limited - you could always do what 2.x did and add an `AsEnumerable` before grouping.

Comment: Is `grp.Key.ID` not unique per record?

Comment: @NetMage Your suggestion is exactly what I have been trying without success...stuffing in the AsEnumerable as the exception suggests.  And yes, it would be (it's the Task's ID).

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL or a replacement for SQL. If you try to just "convert" SQL queries into SQL, you'll get into trouble at some point. That point is now. If you don't want to fix the real problem you can try to run separate queries for the Tasks and Counts. You don't need to group the tasks, so you can load them with a single query. Once you do that, you can extract their IDs and query the Templates, where the Template.TaskID is contained in the list of taskIDs. eg `context.Templates.Where(t=>ids.Contains(t.TaskId).GroupBy(t=>t.TaskId).Select(g=>new {TaskID=g.Key,Count=g.Count())`.

Comment: Another possibility is to group by Task.ID only, and use eg `Max` for all other Task fields

Comment: If the Task ID is unique what is the purpose of the group by? The grp can only contain one record so the `TemplateCount` will always be `1` (empty groups can't be created), so just set `TemplateCount` to `1`. (Unless `ID` can be negative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```cs
var query = (from t in context.Tasks.AsNoTracking()
         join wt in context.WorkTemplates on t.ID equals wt.TaskID into tmp
         from tt in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
         group tt by new { t.ID, t.Name, t.Instructions, t.ManualOnly, t.Timestamp } into grp
         select new
         {
             grp.Key.ID,
             grp.Key.Name,
             grp.Key.Instructions,
             grp.Key.ManualOnly,
             grp.Key.Timestamp,
             TemplateCount = grp.Sum(x => x.ID > 0 ? 1 : 0)
         })
         .Select(x => new Task { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, Instructions = x.Instructions, ManualOnly = x.ManualOnly, Timestamp = x.Timestamp, TemplateCount = x.TemplateCount });
```

Just simplify `tmp.DefaultIfEmpty(new WorkTemplate())`, corrected grouping and replacing `Count` with `Sum`

Comment: The original problem is of course just the `DefaultIfEmpty` overload with parameter (EFC 5 supports conditional `Count`). But this is a ridiculous way of writing EFC query which should not be tolerated. In SQL you might need doing such things, but in EFC to first multiple master table with details, then group it back again just to take the detail count is ridiculous. As people said in comments, in EFC this should simple select from master + `Count()` on collection navigation property.

Comment: @IvanStoev, agree only with Count. It is not rule to have all possible navigations.